# Update the boolean in the main Angular 'thread' async/await

Tags: angular, async-await, kendo-angular-ui

I have the following `async` method. I use a loader in order to update the user interface, visibility of which is based on the `isExporting` flag.

```
public async copyToClipboard(element: HTMLDivElement): Promise<void> {

  this.isExporting = true; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE

  const data = await html2canvas(element, { scale: 1.5 }).then((canvas) => {
    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
      const item = new ClipboardItem({ 'image/png': blob! });
      navigator.clipboard.write([item]).then((res) => {

        this.isExporting = false; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE

        this.notyfService.instance.success({
          message: this.translateService.instant('message.export.success'),
          duration: 2000
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Then I have

```
<button [disabled]="isExporting" (click)="copyToClipboard(container!)">
    <kendo-loader *ngIf="isExporting"> </kendo-loader>
</button>
```

Even if `isExporting` is set to `false` *before* the NotifyService message, I get first of all the service message popup after the clipboard is updated, and only several seconds after the message the loader disappears - `isExporting` is updated in the main 'thread'.

Is there a way to notify the main 'thread' that `isExporting` is updated immediately?

Comment: Have you tried using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`?

Comment: @MikeS. how should we use it?

Comment: There's lots of [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) on that topic ;) In short, you inject it into your class just like services and call `.detectChanges()` from whereever you update template bound variables.

Comment: @MikeS. after your suggestion I have a lot of workaround (see my answer bellow). However, now only second update is OK (to False), not the first (to True)

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't update on `this.isExporting = true;`, you'd need to show me a reproducer because from the code you provided, everything should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Mike S. suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72260114/update-the-boolean-in-the-main-angular-thread-async-await#comment127664411_72260114), I have updated the component like this:

```
constructor(
  private notyfService: NotyfService,
  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {
}


public async copyToClipboard(element: HTMLDivElement): Promise<void> {

  this.isExporting = true;
  this.cd.detectChanges();

  const data = await html2canvas(element).then((canvas) => {
    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
      const item = new ClipboardItem({ 'image/png': blob! });
      navigator.clipboard.write([item]).then((res) => {
        this.notyfService.instance.success({
          message: 'message.export.success',
          duration: 2000
        });

        this.isExporting = false;
        this.cd.detectChanges();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Now the loader is updated OK ***after*** the treatment, however I *still have a delay of 3 seconds* **before** it starts to spin, probably because `isExporting=true` is not detected immediately, even if I use `detectChanges`.